# javascript import module in non module file

Tags: javascript, html, module, scope

How can I use a function inside a html file that is exported from a module?

When I import a js file in my html document like:

```
<script type="module" src="index.jsm"></script>
```

and the js file exports a function or value like:

```
export function test()
```

When I am inside a different module file I can use:

```
import { test } from "./index.jsm";
```

How can I make a button be able to call this function like `onclick="test()"`?

Answer (score 0):

If your script loading is at the end of the body you can use `addEventListener` in a script

```
document.querySelector("#buttonId").addEventListener("click",test)
```

Or you can expose function in your `window` Like so:

```
import { test } from "./index.jsm";
window.test = test
```

This way `onclick="test()"` in HTML will work